# mapping data gives correct results but ends up as undefined in final method

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop, map-function

I have three different arrays. Posts, Categories and Tags. I want to get values from Categories and Tags and merge it with it's Post in the Posts array. Hopefully my code will make it clear what I am trying to achieve.

So after all is done, I am returned a new array with my _.merged data but all the values are undefined. I can't figure out what I am doing wrong here. I'm sure it's a simple mistake I am making.

**Posts array**

```
[
{
    "id": 79,
    "slug": "checkbox-code",
    "type": "post",
    "title": {
        "rendered": "Checkbox code"
    },
    "categories": [
        6
    ],
    "tags": [
        7
    ],
},
{
    "id": 77,
    "slug": "checkbox-style",
    "type": "post",
    "title": {
        "rendered": "Checkbox style"
    },
    "categories": [
        6
    ],
    "tags": [
        8
    ],
},
{
    "id": 75,
    "slug": "checkbox-usage",
    "title": {
        "rendered": "Checkbox usage"
    },
    "categories": [
        6
    ],
    "tags": [
        9
    ],
},
]
```

**Categories array**

```
[
{
    "id": 6,
    "name": "checkbox",
    "slug": "checkbox",
    "taxonomy": "category",
},
{
    "id": 5,
    "name": "buttons",
    "slug": "buttons",
    "taxonomy": "category"
}
]
```

**Tags array**

```
[
{
    "id": 7,
    "name": "code",
    "slug": "code",
    "taxonomy": "post_tag",
},
{
    "id": 8,
    "name": "style",
    "slug": "style",
    "taxonomy": "post_tag",
},
{
    "id": 9,
    "name": "usage",
    "slug": "usage",
    "taxonomy": "post_tag",
}
]
```

**My Code**

```
getTagName = (id) => {
  this.tags.map(tag => {
    if(id == tag.id) {console.log('tag name ' + tag.name)}
    return id == tag.id ? tag.name : null
  })
}

getCatName = (id) => {
  this.cats.map(cat => {
    if(id == cat.id) {console.log('category name ' + cat.slug)}
    return id == cat.id ? cat.slug : null
  })
}

componentWillMount() {
  let arr = [];
  for(let i=0; i<this.posts.length; i++) {
    let tagName = this.getTagName(this.posts[i].tags[0]);
    let catName = this.getCatName(this.posts[i].categories[0]);
    let newObj = {
      "tag_name": tagName,
      "category_name": catName
    }

    _.merge(this.posts[i], newObj);
    arr.push(this.posts[i]);
  }
}
```

**What I get back**

```
[
{
    "id": 79,
    "slug": "checkbox-code",
    "type": "post",
    "title": {
        "rendered": "Checkbox code"
    },
    "categories": [
        6
    ],
    "category_name": undefined,
    "tag_name": undefined,
    "tags": [
        7
    ],
},
{
    "id": 77,
    "slug": "checkbox-style",
    "type": "post",
    "title": {
        "rendered": "Checkbox style"
    },
    "categories": [
        6
    ],
    "category_name": undefined,
    "tag_name": undefined,
    "tags": [
        8
    ],
},
{
    "id": 75,
    "slug": "checkbox-usage",
    "title": {
        "rendered": "Checkbox usage"
    },
    "categories": [
        6
    ],
    "category_name": undefined,
    "tag_name": undefined,
    "tags": [
        9
    ],
},
]
```

when I log the returned values in the getCatName and getTagName methods I get back the correct data. It just doesn't make it to componentWillMount. Thanks for any help.

Here is a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3pLj20nd/3/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the .map() in your getTagName() and getCatName() functions do not really make sense. If you look for a specific Entry it makes sense to use Array.find().

Also you need to return the value. I updated your jsfiddle. https://jsfiddle.net/3pLj20nd/14/

```
getTagName = (id) => {
    return tags.find(tag => {
      return id == tag.id;
    })
}

getCatName = (id) => {
    return cats.find(cat => {
      return id == cat.id;
    })
}

componentWillMount = () => {
    let arr = [];
    for(let i=0; i<posts.length; i++) {
      let tagName = getTagName(posts[i].tags[0]).name;
      let catName = getCatName(posts[i].categories[0]).name;
      let newObj = {
        "tag_name": tagName,
        "category_name": catName
      }
      console.log(newObj);

      _.merge(posts[i], newObj);
      arr.push(posts[i]);
    }

    console.log(arr);
}

componentWillMount();
```

Answer (score 2):

The return statements in both methods are returning from the Array.map() method. You are not returning a value from your `getTagName()` or `getCatName()` functions.

Keep in mind that if you return the results of the map method (ie. `return this.cats.map(...)`), those results will be in the form of an array.

Answer (score 2):

`getTagName` and `getCatName` don't return anything, so `tagName` and `catName` will be undefined.

The `return` statement in `getTagName` belongs to the function you passed to `map` (`tag => {}`). It doesn't make the outer function (`id => {}`) return.

Looks like you're expecting it to work like a `for` loop, where the `return` would stop the loop early and return `tag.name`. `map` doesn't work like that, it always iterates over the whole array, and returns a new array the same length. If you added a return statement into `getTagName` and called `getTagName(8)`, you would get `[ null, 'style', null ]` - that's the result of the inner function for each item in the array.

The method you want to use is `Array.find`.

```
getTagName = id => {
    return this.tags.find( tag => tag.id === id ).name;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is in your getTagName & getCatName functions...

First, functions are not returning any value out of they own scope

```
getCatName = (id) => {
  return cats.map(cat => {
    if(id == cat.id) {console.log('category name ' + cat.slug)}
    return id == cat.id ? cat.slug : null
  })
}
```

But remember, map iterates over all the array length, so it will return full sized array, with matches only on certain indexes, like this:

`tag_name: (3) […] 0: "code", 1: null, 2: null, length: 3`

So maybe you want to change the map for a filter, or work with your mapped data before the return

Hope it helps!